# Kivy android app crashes instantly when opened

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer, p4a

I am trying to develop a simple app that uses google translate's API. The app builds and installs correctly, but when I open the app on my phone, it just crashes, without any kind of error message.

This is my **main.py** file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

from googletrans import Translator

Window.clearcolor = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1)
Window.size = (450, 800)

tr = Translator()

# class in which we are defining action on click
class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def translate(self, text, src, dest):
        print(text, src, dest)
        if text != "":
            self.output_text.text = tr.translate(text, src=src, dest=dest).text
    def speak(self):
        print('speaking')
    def read(self):
        print('reading')

class TranslatorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

myApp = TranslatorApp()

myApp.run()
```

This is my **translator.kv** file:

```
<RootWidget>:

    input_text:input_text
    output_text:output_text
    src_lang:src_lang
    dest_lang:dest_lang

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 5
        padding: 5

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: 5
            size_hint: [1, 0.1]

            Label:
                text: 'Texto a traducir'
                halign: 'left'

            Label:
                text: 'Texto traducido'
                halign: 'left'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: 5
            size_hint: [1, 0.9]

            TextInput:
                id: input_text
                color: [180, 180, 180]
                size_hint: [0.5, 1]
            TextInput:
                id: output_text
                text: "s"
                color: [180, 180, 180]
                size_hint: [0.5, 1]

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: 5
            size_hint: [1, 0.2]

            Button:
                text: 'Hablar'
                color: [0, 255, 255, .67]
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: [0, 0.5, 1, .85]
                on_press: root.speak()
                size_hint: [0.5, 1]

            Button:
                text:'Traducir'
                color: [0, 255, 255, .67]
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: [1, 1, 1, 0.7]
                on_press: root.translate(input_text.text, src_lang.text, dest_lang.text)
                size_hint: [0.5, 1]

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: 5

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    spacing: 5

                    Label:
                        text: 'Idioma de\norigen'
                        halign: 'left'

                    Label:
                        text: 'Idioma de\ndestino'
                        halign: 'left'

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    spacing: 5

                    TextInput:
                        id: src_lang
                        text: 'es'

                    TextInput:
                        id: dest_lang
                        text: 'en'

                Button:
                    text: 'Leer traducción'
                    on_press: root.read()
```

I run the command `buildozer android debug` to build the app.
I am aware that there is `android_new` for the new p4a toolchain, but when I try that I get an error message like this:

`Unknown command/target android_new`

I would add the buildozer.spec file but stackoverflow thinks it is spam

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: Also there hasn't been `android_new` for a long time

Comment: Did you add the googletrans lib to your requirements in your spec file? `requirements = python3,kivy,googletrans`. You can see the log when your app starts if you connect your phone to your pc and enable usb debugging. Then you can you use the command `buildozer android debug deploy logcat`. Your app gets pushed to your phone after compiling has finished and you should see the log information in your terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb answering my own question.

I had added `googletrans` to the spec file, so I thought that wasn't the problem. On one of my attempts to fix the problem, I updated the module, and I saw there were some depencencies for `googletrans` and all I needed to do was to add those dependencies to the requirements too